# Are there mathematical functions to add, substract, multiply, power, or, and that works on multiple elements passed to fuction?

Tags: python, dictionary, calculator, operation

The function should take multiple args and make certain mathematical operations on them (+, -, *, **, |, &). + is a deafult operator. Mathematical fuction is connected to dictionary. Below is what I,ve made so far. But i have problem with mathematical operations (dont take multiple args). Can anyone help?
Examples args: 1, 3, 5, operation='-' --> result: 1 - 3 - 5 = -7

```
def multi_calculator(*args: int, operation='+'):
    import operator
    ops = {
        '+': sum,
        '-': operator.sub,
        '*': operator.mul,
        '**': operator.pow,
        '|': operator.or_,
        '&': operator.and_,
    }

    if operation not in ops:
        result = 'Unknown operator'
    elif len(args) == 0:
        result = 0
    elif len(args) == 1:
        result = args[0]
    else:
        result = ops[operation](args)
    return result


print(multi_calculator(1, 2, 3, operation='-'))
```

Comment: Those are binary operators so [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) provides two-argument functions, if you want to handle more you need to describe the behaviour yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `functools.reduce`:

```py
import operator
import functools

def multi_calculator(*args: int, operation='+'):
    
    ops = {
        '+': operator.add,
        '-': operator.sub,
        '*': operator.mul,
        '**': operator.pow,
        '|': operator.or_,
        '&': operator.and_,
    }

    if operation not in ops:
        result = 'Unknown operator'
    elif len(args) == 0:
        result = 0
    elif len(args) == 1:
        result = args[0]
    else:
        result = functools.reduce(ops[operation], args)
    return result


print(multi_calculator(1, 2, 3, operation='-'))
```